check all assumptions of central limit theorem
I was working on this question and realized that I might not fully understand all the assumptions of the Central Limit Theorem (CLT). I want to verify the assumptions under which the CLT holds. For the CLT to be correct:
(a) All samples must be from identically distributed populations.
(b) All samples must be independent.
(c) The variance must be finite.
(If I forgot any other assumptions, please correct me.)
In the case of Bernoulli random variables with the parameter
p=λn
, because
p
changes over time, the assumption that all samples are identically distributed is violated, and thus we cannot use the CLT in this case. Is this correct?

Your observations are correct in CLT as well as Bernoulli case.
